# Не работает class в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, qt-designer

У меня возникла проблема. В приведённом ниже коде не работает класс `OK_Window()`.

Пожалуйста объясните почему не работает, как это решить и что мне выучить.

Мой код:

```
import cryption as cry
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
print('1')
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def crypte(self):
        self.edit_1 = self.textEdit.text ()
        self.edit_2 = self.textEdit_2.text ()
        self.edit_3 = self.textEdit_3.text ()
        print('4.1')
        print(self.edit_1, self.edit_2, self.edit_3, '1')
        self.qwerty = cry.crypt(self.edit_1, self.edit_2, self.edit_3)
        global qwerty 
        qwerty = self.qwerty
        print(qwerty)
        print('4.2')
        w2.show()
        print('4.3')

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 250)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 501, 51))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.textBrowser_4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_4.setObjectName("textBrowser_4")
        self.textBrowser_5 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 150, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_5.setObjectName("textBrowser_5")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 100, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 501, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 75 18pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        self.push = self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.crypte())

        print('3')

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;\">Зашифровка</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Введите язык (eng, ru, ru-eng)</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_4.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Введите спец-код от 1 до 100</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_5.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Что хотите зашифровать?</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат"))
        print('2')

class OK_Window(Ui_MainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 100)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 470, 150))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.a = self.label.text()
        print(self.a)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", qwerty))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    w2 = OK_Window()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    print('end')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.** 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
# ??? import cryption as cry

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, \
    QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 250)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 501, 51))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        
        self.textBrowser_4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_4.setObjectName("textBrowser_4")
        
        self.textBrowser_5 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 150, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_5.setObjectName("textBrowser_5")
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 100, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 501, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 75 18pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
#        self.push = self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.crypte())

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;\">Зашифровка</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Введите язык (eng, ru, ru-eng)</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_4.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Введите спец-код от 1 до 100</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_5.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Что хотите зашифровать?</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат"))
    
    
# ------------> vvvvvvvvvvv<>vvvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------
class OK_Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)                                              # +++
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)               # ???
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 470, 150))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.push = self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.crypte)

# ???        self.a = self.label.text()
# ???        print(self.a)                  
        
    def crypte(self):
        self.edit_1 = self.textEdit.text()
        self.edit_2 = self.textEdit_2.text()
        self.edit_3 = self.textEdit_3.text()
        print(self.edit_1, self.edit_2, self.edit_3, '1')

# ------------------> ??? <--------------------------------------------------        
#        self.qwerty = cry.crypt(self.edit_1, self.edit_2, self.edit_3)
        
        self.qwerty = 'qwerty'
        print(self.qwerty) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    
    w2 = OK_Window()                                                 # 
    w2.show()                                                        # +++
    
#    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> с вашим кодом у меня перестали работать `QLineEdit` введения языка и введения спец-кода, вы не знаете почему? 
> Я просто не могу ввести туда текст, курсор остаётся обычным, 
> а не в форме **`I`**

Sorry, но код ваш. Я же вам отметил как **`# ???`** и строки `self.label...` - что это?  Вы этим `self.label` накрываете почти все в вашем окне, потому что `self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 470, 150))`

Научитесь использовать менеджеры компоновки ([**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html))  !!!

```
# ??? import cryption as cry

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, \
    QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 250)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 501, 51))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        
        self.textBrowser_4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_4.setObjectName("textBrowser_4")
        
        self.textBrowser_5 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 150, 161, 51))
        self.textBrowser_5.setObjectName("textBrowser_5")
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 100, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 341, 51))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 501, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 75 18pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
#        self.push = self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.crypte())

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;\">Зашифровка</span></p></body></html>"))


        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Введите язык (eng, ru, ru-eng)</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_4.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Введите спец-код от 1 до 100</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_5.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt; font-weight:600;\">Что хотите зашифровать?</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат"))
    
    
# ------------> vvvvvvvvvvv<>vvvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------
class OK_Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)                                              # +++

# ???
#        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)               # ???
#        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 470, 150))            # 470, 150 ???
#        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.push = self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.crypte)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.textEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите язык')
        self.textEdit_2.setPlaceholderText('Введите спец-код от 1 до 100')
        self.textEdit_3.setPlaceholderText('Введите то, что хотите зашифровать')
        self.textEdit.setFocus()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

# ???        self.a = self.label.text()
# ???        print(self.a)                  
        
    def crypte(self):
        self.edit_1 = self.textEdit.text()
        self.edit_2 = self.textEdit_2.text()
        self.edit_3 = self.textEdit_3.text()
        print(self.edit_1, self.edit_2, self.edit_3, '1')

# ------------------> ??? <--------------------------------------------------        
#        self.qwerty = cry.crypt(self.edit_1, self.edit_2, self.edit_3)
        
        self.qwerty = 'qwerty'
        print(self.qwerty) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w2 = OK_Window() 
    w2.show()        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S. Nick, извините пожалуйста, с вашим кодом у меня перестали работать QLineEdit введения языка и введения спец-кода, вы не знаете почему? Я просто не могу ввести туда текст, курсор остаётся обычным,  а не в форме I

Comment: @Yraron я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: спасибо вам огромное, извините за глупые вопросы, я только учусь.

Comment: @Yraron пожалуйста. Удачи вам.